# Integer Linear (ILP / MILP) Formulation for Collision Avoidance of Convex Polytopes / Polyhedra

Tags: linear-programming, polygons, integer-programming, convex-geometry, collision-detection

I am looking for a possibility to avoid the collision of two convex polytopes using (mixed integer) linear programming. I know how I can detect a collision (Akgunduz, A., Banerjee, P., and Mehrotra, S. (March 14, 2005). "A Linear Programming Solution for Exact Collision Detection ." ASME. J. Comput. Inf. Sci. Eng. March 2005; 5(1): 48–55. https://doi.org/10.1115/1.1846053):

Vertices of polytopes are given: vj, wj

Weights are variables: αj ⩾ 0, βj ⩾ 0

∑vj αj − ∑wj βj = 0 (1)

∑αj = 1 (2)

∑βj = 1 (3)

Equation (1) applies to each of the x, y, and z coordinates of the vertices for P1 and  P2. Here the presence of a feasible solution indicates a collision. If no solution is found, no collision exists. What I am now looking for is the opposite. I am looking for a feasible solution for no-collision and a not feasible solution if the polytopes collide. How can I change the equations to get this? It is also important for me, that the collision avoidance is not included in the objective function, since the objective parameters are others. The equations should just create a feasible solution space for non-collsion solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two convex polytopes are disjoint if and only if there is an affine hyperplane which separates them.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek You should make this an answer.

Comment: I tried the separating hyperplane approach, however I need to add rotation to the problem. If rotation shall be taken into account as optimization variable I see no possibility to build the separating hyperplane search as linear system for a MILP (for rotation the sine and cosine functions are necessary, so it is rather a MIConstraintP or so). Thats why I was looking for another approach (see above). There rotation can be easily included by adding the rotation to the constraints. However I need to reverse the feasibility space (as stated above) and I don't know how to do this.